# MySQL NOT IN taking forever

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

This query used to take 4 to 5 seconds to run. Here are my table stats:

students Table: 4200 Rows

idtrack Table 15000 Rows

and here is my query:

```
SELECT students.student_id
FROM students
WHERE students.grade_level ='12' 
AND students.student_id 
NOT IN (
    SELECT idtrack.student_id
    FROM idtrack
    WHERE idtrack.event_id ='33'
)
```

It is now taking 30 seconds to complete this query. Can someone please help me optimize/refactor? Thanks in advance.

Comment: sub queries always takes time, be sure you have indexes and look at the execution plan of query

Comment: If you post your tables schema, it's better.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try

```
SELECT students.student_id
FROM students
LEFT JOIN idtrack ON idtrack.event_id='33' AND idtrack.student_id = students.student_id
WHERE students.grade_level ='12' 
AND idtrack.student_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I tried this and still was receiving slow results. I ended up doing it with PHP and array intesect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot create primary kays for tables?

Comment: I have primary keys for all tables.

Comment: its desirable to create indexes on binded fields `students.student_id` `idtrack.event_id`

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` is usually a lot faster since, in your case, it allows MySQL to short-circuit when it finds a record in `idtrack` that contradicts the `NOT EXISTS` clause.

```
SELECT students.student_id
FROM students
WHERE students.grade_level ='12' 
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT idtrack.student_id
FROM idtrack
WHERE idtrack.event_id ='33'
AND idtrack.student_id = students.student_id
)
```

Comment: With a 4:1 ratio on a unique indexed field? I'd be very surprised.

Comment: @symcbean: I didn't notice the number of records for each table.

Answer (score 0):

What about join students on idtrack, and filter "where students.grade_level=12 and idtrack.event_id <> 33"?  Join should be faster than a subquery.  Simple equality/inequality *much* faster than "not in".

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the create table commands and explain output its rather difficult. But you might try:

```
SELECT students.student_id
FROM students LEFT JOIN idtrack
    ON students.id=idtrack.student_id
    AND idtrack.event_id ='33'
WHERE students.grade_level ='12' 
AND idtrack.student_id IS NULL
```

BTW if idtrack.event_id and students.grade_level are declared as numbers then they shouldn't be quoted.